# How to transform one state space model into different state space model?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, linear-transformations, substitution

First of all I would like to apologize if I have chosen wrong forum. My question is related to the electrical engineering but basically it is a mathematical problem.

I have the state space model of the three phase squirrel cage induction motor. The state space model contains in the system matrix parameters of the $T$ equivalent circuit (the equivalent circuit is basically an electrical circuit modeling the machine)

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{sT} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{rT}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\alpha\cdot\mathbf{E} & \beta\cdot\mathbf{E}-\gamma\cdot p_p\cdot\omega_m\cdot\mathbf{J} \\
R_r\cdot\frac{L_h}{L_r}\cdot\mathbf{E} & -\frac{R_r}{L_r}\cdot\mathbf{E} + \omega_m\cdot p_p\cdot \mathbf{J}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{sT} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{rT}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta\cdot\mathbf{E} \\
\mathbf{Z}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\hat{\mathbf{u}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{sT}
$$

$$
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{sT}  
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{E} & \mathbf{Z}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{sT} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{rT}
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
where the auxiliary variables $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ have following values
$\alpha = \frac{R_s + R_r\cdot\frac{L^2_h}{L^2_r}}{L_{s\sigma} + \frac{L_h}{L_r}\cdot L_{r\sigma}}$, $\beta = \frac{\frac{R_r\cdot L_h}{L^2_r}}{L_{s\sigma} + \frac{L_h}{L_r}\cdot L_{r\sigma}}$, $\gamma = \frac{\frac{L_h}{L_r}}{L_{s\sigma} + \frac{L_h}{L_r}\cdot L_{r\sigma}}$, $\delta = \frac{1}{L_{s\sigma} + \frac{L_h}{L_r}\cdot L_{r\sigma}}$. The parameter $R_s$ is the resistance of the stator winding, $R_r$ is the resistance of the rotor winding, $L_h$ is the magnetizing inductance, $L_r$ is the rotor inductance, $L_{s\sigma}$ is the leakage inductance of the stator winding and $L_{r\sigma}$ is the leakage inductance of the rotor winding.

### T equivalent circuit

[image]

The $\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{J}, \mathbf{Z}$ matrices have following meaning

$$
\mathbf{E} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf{J} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf{Z} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My intention is to transform the above given state space model to a different state space model which will contain parameters of the $\Gamma$ equivalent circuit of the induction motor.

### $\Gamma$ equivalent circuit

[image]

This transformation basically means that the state variables changes due to the fact that the leakage inductance of the stator winding has been moved onto the rotor side

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{s\Gamma} = \hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{sT}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{s\Gamma} = b\cdot\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{rT} = \frac{L_s}{L_h}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{rT}
\end{equation}

or in matrix form

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{s\Gamma} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{r\Gamma}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{E} & \mathbf{Z} \\
\mathbf{Z} & b\cdot\mathbf{Z}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{sT} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{rT}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

which means

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}_T 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{sT} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{rT}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{E} & \mathbf{Z} \\
\mathbf{Z} & \frac{1}{b}\cdot\mathbf{Z}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{s\Gamma} \\
\hat{\mathbf{\psi}}^{\alpha,\beta}_{r\Gamma}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\mathbf{T}
\cdot
\mathbf{x}_{\Gamma}
\end{equation}

The last matrix equation enables to move from the $T$ based state space model to the $\Gamma$ state space model. Because in case we use it in the $T$ based state space model

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\mathbf{x}}_T &=& \mathbf{A}_T\cdot \mathbf{x}_T + \textbf{B}_T\cdot \mathbf{u} \nonumber \\
\mathbf{y}_T &=& \mathbf{C}_T\cdot\mathbf{x}_T \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

we have

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{x}_{\Gamma}\right) 
=
\mathbf{A}_T\cdot\left(\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{x}_{\Gamma}\right) + \mathbf{B}_T\cdot \mathbf{u}_T 
$$

$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}_{\Gamma} = \mathbf{T}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{A}_T\cdot\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{x}_{\Gamma} + \mathbf{T}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{B}_T\cdot\mathbf{u}_T
$$

$$
\mathbf{y}_{T}
=
\mathbf{y}_{\Gamma}
=
\mathbf{C}_T\cdot\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{x}_{\Gamma}
$$

From the last set of the matrix equations we can write formulas for transforming the matrices of the $T$ based state space model into the $\Gamma$ based state space model

$$
\mathbf{A}_{\Gamma} = \mathbf{T}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{A}_T\cdot\mathbf{T}
$$

$$
\mathbf{B}_{\Gamma} = \mathbf{T}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{B}_T
$$

$$
\mathbf{C}_{\Gamma} = \mathbf{C}_T\cdot\mathbf{T}
$$

My problem is how to write the matrices of the $\Gamma$ based state space model i.e. $\mathbf{A}_{\Gamma}, \mathbf{B}_{\Gamma}, \mathbf{C}_{\Gamma}$ in such a manner that they contain in their elements only the parameters of the $\Gamma$ equivalent circuit i.e. stator resistance $R_S$, magnetizing inductance $L_M$, total leakage inductance $L_L$ and rotor resistance $R_R$. There are following formulas for conversion of the parameters of the $T$ equivalent circuit into the parameters of the $\Gamma$ equivalent circuit

$$
R_S = R_s
$$

$$
L_M = L_s
$$

$$
L_L = L_r\cdot\frac{L^2_s}{L^2_h} - L_s
$$

$$
R_R = R_r\cdot\frac{L^2_s}{L^2_h}
$$

I have attempted to made some modifications in the elements of the matrices aiming to exploit the formulas for the $R_S$,$L_M$,$L_L$ $R_R$ but I always stuck in a situation where let's
say $R_r$ is multiplied by the desired "transform" coefficient $b=\frac{L_s}{L_h}$ but the necessary modifications create very complex expression from the rest of the matrix element which doesn't contain none of the formulas for the $R_S$,$L_M$,$L_L$,$R_R$. I have also attempted to use the *wxMaxima* software for the symbolic calculations but without success.

One observation I have made. If I chose different transform coefficient $b=\frac{L_h}{L_r}$ which corresponds to the another equivalent circuit called $\Gamma^{-1}$

### $\Gamma^{-1}$ equivalent circuit

[image]

I am able to get correct state space model based on the above mentioned steps and below given formulas for conversion of the parameters of the $T$ equivalent circuit into the parameters of the $\Gamma^{-1}$ equivalent circuit

$$
R_S = R_s
$$

$$
L_M = L_h\cdot\frac{L_h}{L_r}
$$

$$
L_L = L_{s\sigma} + \frac{L_h}{L_r}\cdot L_{r\sigma}
$$

$$
R_R = R_r\cdot\frac{L^2_h}{L^2_r}
$$

This fact proofs in my opinion the correctness of the derived formulas for the transformation of the matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am not wrong but I think that the solution is very simple. Due to the fact that the transition between both the state space models has been done via application of the transform matrix $\mathbf{T}$ on the system matrix $\mathbf{A_T}$ and the input matrix $\mathbf{B_T}$ I think that I can simply substitute the following formulas into the elements of the $\mathbf{A_{\Gamma}}$ and $\mathbf{B_{\Gamma}}$ matrices and get the state space model related to the $\Gamma$ equivalent circuit

$$L_{s\sigma} = L_s - L_h$$
$$L_{r\sigma} = L_r - L_h$$
$$L_r = L_L + L_M$$
$$R_s = R_S$$
$$L_h = L_M$$
$$R_r = R_R$$
$$L_s = L_M$$